# Problem with object handling in Javascript forEach function

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm trying to do an object manipulation in javascript, but it's not working as expected.

The code is this:

```
let data = [{
    "Code": "COD01",
    "Size Options": "85-90-95-100",
}, {
    "Code": "COD02",
    "Size Options": "85-90-95-100",
}];

let newData = [];
data.forEach(function(product) {
    newData.push(product);

    if (product["Size Options"].indexOf('-') > -1) {
        let variations = product["Size Options"].split('-');
        let prodVariation = product;
        variations .forEach(function(variation) {

            prodVariation["Code"] = prodVariation["Code"] + '-' + variation;
            newData.push(prodVariation);
            console.log(prodVariation);
        });
    }
});

console.log('New data:');
console.log(JSON.stringify(newData, null, 4));
```

The intention was to look like this in the `newData` variable:

```
[
    {
        "Code": "COD01",
        "Size Options": "85-90-95-100"
    },
    {
        "Code": "COD01-85",
        "Size Options": "85-90-95-100"
    },
    {
        "Code": "COD01-90",
        "Size Options": "85-90-95-100"
    },
    {
        "Code": "COD01-95",
        "Size Options": "85-90-95-100"
    },
    {
        "Code": "COD01-100",
        "Size Options": "85-90-95-100"
    },
    {
        "Code": "COD02",
        "Size Options": "85-90-95-100"
    },
    {
        "Code": "COD02-85",
        "Size Options": "85-90-95-100"
    },
    {
        "Code": "COD02-90",
        "Size Options": "85-90-95-100"
    },
    {
        "Code": "COD02-95",
        "Size Options": "85-90-95-100"
    },
    {
        "Code": "COD02-100",
        "Size Options": "85-90-95-100"
    }
]
```

But it's looking like this:

```
[
    {
        "Code": "COD01-85-90-95-100",
        "Size Options": "85-90-95-100"
    },
    {
        "Code": "COD01-85-90-95-100",
        "Size Options": "85-90-95-100"
    },
    {
        "Code": "COD01-85-90-95-100",
        "Size Options": "85-90-95-100"
    },
    {
        "Code": "COD01-85-90-95-100",
        "Size Options": "85-90-95-100"
    },
    {
        "Code": "COD01-85-90-95-100",
        "Size Options": "85-90-95-100"
    },
    {
        "Code": "COD02-85-90-95-100",
        "Size Options": "85-90-95-100"
    },
    {
        "Code": "COD02-85-90-95-100",
        "Size Options": "85-90-95-100"
    },
    {
        "Code": "COD02-85-90-95-100",
        "Size Options": "85-90-95-100"
    },
    {
        "Code": "COD02-85-90-95-100",
        "Size Options": "85-90-95-100"
    },
    {
        "Code": "COD02-85-90-95-100",
        "Size Options": "85-90-95-100"
    }
]
```

I've tried to solve the problem in several ways, both with jQuery and Javascript. I also tried copying the object, because it seems that it is making the change on top of another change, instead of taking the base object, but I couldn't solve it. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: `let prodVariation = product;` You need to create a copy of this object inside the loop - right now you're creating it once outside the loop and mutating it multiple times in the inner loop, and pushing that singular object multiple times, instead of creating (and mutating) a copy each time

Comment: Thanks for helping @CertainPerformance. I put ```let prodVariation = structuredClone(product);``` inside loop and it worked. I was not aware of this function, but now everything worked, thank you very much :D